# MySQL / PHP: Select Where with multiple conditions does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a following database entry:

```
id                date                start_time 
1                 2015-12-25          08:00:00
2                 2015-12-30          08:00:00
3                 2015-12-30          09:00:00
```

Now I just want to select the date of those entries where both `start_time` entries `08:00:00` and `09:00:00` exists.

I tried to use this SQL query:

```
$sqlquery = mysqli_query($myconnection,"SELECT date 
                                        FROM mytable 
                                        WHERE start_time LIKE '08:00:00' 
                                        AND '09:00:00'") or die ("crashed");
```

But it returns me both dates `2015-12-25` and `2015-12-30`. It should only return `2015-12-30` because for this date `08:00:00` and `09:00:00` exists.

I want to select those dates which have an entry for `08:00:00` and `09:00:00` too.

It should not select dates with only an entry for `08:00:00` but none for `09:00:00` and also not those which have an entry for `09:00:00` but none for `08:00:00`.

Comment: Do you want only rows where `start_time = '08:00:00' OR start_time = '09:00:00'` OR dates where the time in `start_time` is anything BETWEEN `08:00:00 and 09:00:00` This may sound like a subtile difference but it is not

Comment: will the times always be the same (i.e. 8:00 and 9:00)? or do you need to see a count of the start times of a specific date?

Comment: Okay, I see I need to explain more clear. I want to select those dates which have an entry for 08:00:00 and 09:00:00 too. It should not select dates with only an entry for 08:00:00 but none for 09:00:00 and also not those which have an entry for 09:00:00 but none for 08:00:00.

Comment: Why only  `08:00:00` or  `09:00:00` ?? Not  `08:00:01` or  `09:00:02`

Comment: Thats not important @NanaPartykar I need this strict declarations for my further code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RyanVincent. Added the clarification

Comment: @NanaPartykar You can argue with how someone attempts to achieve a requirement, but NOT with the requirement itself. Afterall that is something that only they can be sure of, and (s)he seems pretty sure

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I'm just clarifying my doubt.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right. Such questions do not help to achieve the solution.

Comment: @coder as there are different ways to solve this, it's good to ask your requirements, because if the times would change 1 minute the sql query would stop working if it was hard coded to 8:00.

Comment: Yes of course, I understand @davejal - Do you know a solution? I would appreciate it if you could post it.

Comment: check my answer, but still, it depends on what you want with the data and how you want to format it

Comment: @coder check out my edited answer, both give the result of '2015-12-30' as you required and option 1 gives you more room to expand

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `like` for date/time columns.  Here, you seem to want `between`:

```
SELECT date
FROM mytable
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00';
```

Your original formulation is parsed like this:

```
WHERE (start_time LIKE '08:00:00') AND '09:00:00'
```

The second part is a string value in a boolean/integer context.  It gets converted to 9, which is always true.  So, the `where` clause ends up being equivalent to:

```
WHERE start_time = '08:00:00'
```

EDIT:

Your clarification changes my understanding of the question.  If you want days that have both times, use aggregation:

```
SELECT date 
FROM mytable 
WHERE start_time IN ('08:00:00', '09:00:00')
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I think you are assuming too much by coding a `BETWEEN` as it is far from obvious from the question. _(not my dv)_

Comment: @coder . . . I misinterpreted the original question (my answer was an intelligent guess as to what you really want).  A simple aggregation with `HAVING` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you basically want to select date that has both '08:00:00' and '09:00:00', then you should not use 'BETWEEN'.
try this query:

```
SELECT t1.date
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
INNER JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t1.date = t3.date
INNER JOIN mytable AS t4 ON t1.date = t4.date
WHERE t1.start_time = '08:00:00' 
    AND t2.start_time = '09:00:00'
    AND t3.start_time = '10:00:00'
    AND t4.start_time = '11:00:00'
GROUP BY t1.date
```

or you can try another approach

```
SELECT t1.date
FROM mytable AS t1
GROUP BY t1.date
HAVING SUM(IF(t1.start_time = '08:00:00', 1, 0)) > 0
AND SUM(IF(t1.start_time = '09:00:00', 1, 0)) > 0
AND SUM(IF(t1.start_time = '10:00:00', 1, 0)) > 0
AND SUM(IF(t1.start_time = '11:00:00', 1, 0)) > 0
```

Comment: Except you can use `=` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: This works just fine! Thank you. Could you please tell me how the code would look like if I had 5 times and only those dates which have all 5 times get selected? Like 08:00:00, 09:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00

Comment: This is exactly what I warned about in your question, now 8:00:00 is hard coded

Comment: yes, it would be long query as the start_time conditions is added :). i added another approach

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there are different ways to achieve it depending on what you actually want to do with the result.

1. Easy->Just count the records with specific dates

   ```
   select date, count(start_time) 
   from mytable 
   group by date 
   having count(start_time) > 1
   ```

2.Advanced->Display the records by using a case

```
   select * 
   from (
          Select date,
                case when start_time = '08:00:00' then 1 end as startat8, 
                case when start_time = '09:00:00' then 1 end as startat9 
           from mytable
         ) a 
    where a.startat8=1 and a.startat9=1;
```

Comment: option 1 will not look at the specific times in the table just if there are more then 1 entry and option 2 will specifically look for 8:00 and 9:00, be sure the time is written in the db exactly like it is in the query

Comment: there was an error with option 1, I updated the answer

Comment: I'm sorry both options do not work. The first one delivers no result and when running the second one the mysqli query dies.

Comment: hold on I will test option 2, but have you tried option 1 after my update?

Comment: @Riggsfolly thanks, but now the time in the first case is not right

Comment: I just reformatted so people could actually see the code easier, I did not change the time, check back in the edit history if you are confused